# Issues with percentage closer filtering

Tags: opengl, fragment-shader, shadows, shadow-mapping, shadowmap

I'm trying to code a simple game via OpenGL C++.
I've implemented a point light, parallax effect with textures, objects from blender etc. but I seem to have an issue with my percentage closer filtering implementation. The shadows are casted on top of a floor which is just a rendered texture below my objects. Im pretty new with how shadows work in OpenGL. This is my attempt to achieve pcf in the fragment shader:

```
in vec4 shadowMapCoord;

layout(binding = 10) uniform sampler2D shadowMapTex;
// area around each fragment that will be sampled
const int pcfCount = 10;

void main(): 
float shadowFactor = 0.0f;  
for (int x =-pcfCount; x <= pcfCount; x++){     // x offset from inner pixel
        for (int y =-pcfCount; y <= pcfCount; y++){     // y offset from inner pixel
            shadowFactor += textureProjOffset(shadowMapTex, shadowMapCoord, ivec2(x,y));
        }   
    }
    float visibility = shadowFactor;
```

Does someone maybe spot any issue with my implementation of `textureProjOffset()` or can I achieve pcf with another type of implementation?

[image: Here is how it looks in the game]

Comment: Is there a specific problem with this code that we can help you solve?

Comment: i guess i am doing something wrong in the code or that i have missed something, since i dont get any pcf effect on the shadows